# How to provide a buffer instance as Source in a MediaElement in windows phone 7

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

I have a buffer object as source which I need to play in windows phone 7(video). Is there a way to provide a buffer source as the input for the MediaElement either through the xaml or programmatically? thanks.

```
<MediaElement x:Name="media" Source="xbox.wmv" Width="300" Height="300" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mediaElement can have it's "source" specified as a `Uri` by setting [`Source`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.source%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) directly. You can also call [`SetSource()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190669%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) to pass it a stream.

If your buffer object is a stream you shoudl call `SetSource()`. Note that you can implement a custom format using a [MediaStreamSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediastreamsource%28VS.95%29.aspx) if need be.